# Convert String to JSON to find values that may/may not be present

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I have the following String:

```
{
  "version": "1.2",
  "actor": {
    "id": "4381991279",
    "auth_claims": [
      "USERNAME",
      "PASSWORD"
    ],
    "auth_state": "LOGGEDIN",
    "account_number": "4796109829347323858",
    "encrypted_account_number": "",
    "party_id": "4796109829347323858",
    "user_type": "API_CALLER"
  },
  "auth_token": "****",
  "auth_token_type": "SESSION_TOKEN",
  "global_session_id": "****",
  "last_validated": 1608492054.561,
  "scopes": [
    "*"
  ],
  "claims": {
    "subject_payer_id": "",
    "application_name": "",
    "actor_payer_id": "",
    "consent_id": null
  },
  "edge_authorization": {
    "policy_decision": "PERMIT",
    "obligations": []
  },
  "subjects": [
    {
      "subject": {
        "id": "4381991279",
        "auth_claims": [
          "USERNAME",
          "PASSWORD"
        ],
        "auth_state": "LOGGEDIN",
        "account_number": "4796109829347323858",
        "encrypted_account_number": "",
        "party_id": "4796109829347323858",
        "authenticating_user": true,
        "user_type": "CONSUMER"
      },
      "features": []
    }
  ],
  "signature": ""
}
```

I want to capture the "auth_claims" array and store its values as a string. I am looking for the "auth_claims" array that is inside the "subjects" array.

The code I have is as follows:

```
private static List<String> getAuthClaims(String securityContext) {
        List<String> securityContextClaims = new ArrayList<>();
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(securityContext) && securityContext.contains("auth_claims")) {
            JSONObject securityContextJson = new JSONObject(securityContext);
            JSONArray auth_claims = securityContextJson.getJSONArray("subjects");
            auth_claims.forEach(claim -> securityContextClaims.add(claim.toString()));
            return securityContextClaims;
        }
        logger.warn("Security Context Is Empty or Missing Auth Claims");
        return null;
    }
```

However this would get all of objects inside the subjects and I only want to get the auth claims. How can I skip to only the auth_claims to store those values?

Comment: A tag specifying the language (that looks like C#) is missing. You could access easily to your JSON info using a class to store it, could use https://json2csharp.com/ to generate the code.

Comment: sorry - its java :)

Comment: That JSON to Class converter also supports Java, by the way.

Comment: the converter is not needed, i want to get the values from auth_claims and store it as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way of solving it with jackson

```
private static List<String> getAuthClaims(String securityContext) throws JsonProcessingException {
    if(securityContext.contains("auth_claims")) {
        List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(securityContext);
        JsonNode subjectsNode = root.get("subjects");
        for(JsonNode subject : subjectsNode) {
            JsonNode authClaims = subject.findValue("auth_claims");
            if(authClaims != null) {
                authClaims.forEach(claim -> ans.add(claim.asText()));
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    return null;
}
```

this way would also work with multiple subjects

jackson dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

worth mentioning that it would be cleaner to create classes that represent the json object and use them with mapping, these [tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) could help with that

Comment: thanks, i realize using the objectmapper.readvValue() with a custom class to represent the data is better.

Comment: ofcs, if my ans help please consider marking it as accepted